# could not download symlink from artifactory using jfrog cli

Tags: artifactory, jfrog-cli

```
jfrog rt dl --symlinks=true generic-local/latest.tgz
```

Getting "Incorrect Usage".
jfrog cli version 1.18.0.
Is it possible to download a symlink data from jfrog CLI?

Answer (score 0):

In jfrog cli, --symlink is a parameter used for preserving the soft links structure in Artifactory during the upload.
So for downloading you can use the following command

```
jfrog rt dl generic-local/latest.tgz
```

In addition, when downloading symlinks stored in Artifactory, the CLI can verify that the file to which the symlink points actually exists and that it has the correct SHA1 checksum. To add this validation, you should use the --validate-symlinks option with the download command.

Comment: Thannk you Shahin, I tried with --validate-symlinks option and --dry-run also. Its not downloading anything and failing the command.